# rEFInd no longer running on dual boot macbook pro

Tags: dual-boot, macbook-pro

dual boot on macbook pro 9,2 osx 10,9,1 and ubuntu 13,10 after an unrelated upgrade (to iMovie on osx) rEFInd no longer opens on re boot and i have no options on which os to boot? i tried to boot from the ubuntu 13,10 cd but it gets to a black screen and never runs the cd.

Comment: If you hold the option key as the computer restarts you should have the option to boot into Ubuntu (it may be called Windows). Once you boot into Ubuntu, rEFInd should work again (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when you do OS X updates (even if they seem unrelated, and especially if you try to upgrade your OS X to Mavericks). 
If you still have the binary files you used to install rEFInd try running the install.sh script again on OS X - there is no need to uninstall rEFInd first, just run the script again. That should fix your issue.